# what's a good structure for handling multiple orders of a customer for mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database

newbie here. I'm trying to figure out what's the best database structure for handling multiple orders of a customer. currently i have 3 tables

**EDITED:** database structure

linkk here : [My current database structure](http://prntscr.com/6awkiq)

now my problem is. how can i handle multiple orders by a customer?
for example, i ordered 3 shirts. In my current structure set up. I would just

```
SELECT * FROM orders;
```

and it would just print all the rows from the order. now, how would i know that the 3 orders (those 3 rows in my order table) is from one transaction of a specific customer. imagine having several more from other customers.

ist right to have 1 more table? like

http://prntscr.com/6awi14

what would be the fields? and how would i connect these to my order details?
please correct me. I'm still learning mysql stuffs.

I know I'm missing one more table. but i still couldnt wrap it out it my head. why.can someone enlighten me. thankss :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the order from it's order items. An order has an order number, a total and belongs to a client (that is you need a foreign key).

The order items table contains the item reference, price and so on. It must have a column `order_id` that references the order table using a primary key.

Your sketches do not show foreign keys, but they are very basic to the database design.

If you use InnoDB, you have to create them in the database. If you use MyIsam, you cannot create them in the database, but you have to implement them in your application logic.